# Humphrey meets Laureen in town

Tags: logical-deduction

Laureen is talking with Humphrey: "if the weather is good on Sunday I will go to the horse races. I will also bring my friend Sam with me, if he feels ok". on Sunday afternoon Humphrey meets Laureen in town.

which is true?
a) Sam is not well
b) It is raining and Sam is not well
c) It is good weather, but Sam didn't want to go to the horse races
d) It is good weather, but Sam isn't well
e) It is raining

Comment: Are the horse races "in town"? Is raining "not good weather"?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This is not a site for your homework.

Comment: @Deusovi This is not my homework

Comment: @user26302: In any case, if it's copied from somewhere, you must give credit.

Comment: @Deusovi what is the credit?

Comment: @user26302 reference to the book, website, person who made it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Humphrey

> is not at the races.

Therefore,

> It is not "good weather".

Therefore,

> e) it is raining.

Additional Notes:

> Humphrey being at the races was not conditional on Sam's health.  Sam may be well, he may not, that's not known however.